# Android Spinner, needs a menu for each item

Tags: java, android, xml

First of all, I'm a beginner in android
I have a spinner that needs specific menu for each item on the spinner.
This is the basic spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/building_type"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

and these are the items on the spinner

```
<string-array name="building_types">
    <item>W1</item>
    <item>W2</item>
    <item>S1</item>
    <item>S2</item>
    <item>S3</item>
    <item>S4</item>
    <item>S5</item>
    <item>C1</item>
    <item>C2</item>
    <item>C3</item>
    <item>PC1</item>
    <item>PC2</item>
    <item>RM1</item>
    <item>RM2</item>
    <item>URM</item>
</string-array>
```

and this is the class for the spinner

```
states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.building_types);


    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.building_type);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            //do what?
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

when an user choose an item on the spinner, i want some specific radio boxes comes out.
basically, it is just like

```
if building_types=="w1"
then show radiobox1
elseif building_types=="w2"
then show radiobox2
and so on
```

all i have read on tuts is only toast some text after it got selected.

any tuts similiar to this case maybe? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're really close to what you're seeking.

The if statements should be added to the `onItemSelected` method for example like this:

```
String selectedItem = dataAdapter.getItem(position);
if(selectedItem.equals("w1")) {
   radioBox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else if(selectedItem.equals("w2") {
   radioBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: your method worked like a charm thanks.
but i have one problem more.
when i choose "w1", they visible.
but when i choose "w2", the previous radiobox doesn't go invisible/gone.

I've set them gone by the way.
any solution? @Doppie

Comment: Hmm the only solution to do that is to update ALL radioBoxes. So when radioBox1 should be visible set radioBox2 invisible. A view has three visibility states: `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE`(just invisible but not removed from the layout) and `View.GONE`(completely removed from the layout)

Comment: Btw if the answer was correct please vote it up :)